# Tridion 2011 SP1 | Porting while import throwing error

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

We are working on Tridion 2011 SP1. While importing the packages (which we have created through 'Content Porter'), we are getting the error mentioned below.

Here is the complete list of steps followed:

1. Selected the package to be imported.
2. Didn't exclude any Dependency
3. While importing the hierarchy till the home publication node is by default selected.
4. If we proceed with this then we got error

But if we only select children items and not including the parent node then the import is successful.

Error Log:

```
<tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="false">
  <![CDATA[A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_PUBLICATIONS_FINDBPCONFLICTS".]]>
  <tcm:Token>EDA_PUBLICATIONS_FINDBPCONFLICTS</tcm:Token>
</tcm:Line>
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is most likely due to the unresolved dependencies inside the blueprint. It is possible that your mapping is wrong and pointing wrong/non –existing location. Try deselecting the dependencies one by one to find out the exact culprit and check with this where you are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The stored procedure in question suggests that there is an issue with blueprint conflicts - you're trying to import something on Publication A while Publication B (a child publication of A) already has an item with the same name in the same location.

Have you tried running "Discover potential problems before the actual import"? (checkbox in the Content Porter interface)